How can I get the MSI Property: Version value (as found in MECM's detection method rule) using Powershell?
Within MECM, when I setup a Detection Rule and I browse to the MSI file, it not only imports the Product Code, but also an MSI version number.
Using (Get-Item $msiPath).VersionInfo | fl, the output is as below, how can I mimic what MECM is doing to find the 1.0.0000 property value shown in the image below?
OriginalFilename  : 
FileDescription   : 
ProductName       : 
Comments          : 
CompanyName       : 
FileName          : filenameandpath.msi
FileVersion       : 
ProductVersion    : 
IsDebug           : False
IsPatched         : False
IsPreRelease      : False
IsPrivateBuild    : False
IsSpecialBuild    : False
Language          : 
LegalCopyright    : 
LegalTrademarks   : 
PrivateBuild      : 
SpecialBuild      : 
FileVersionRaw    : 0.0.0.0
ProductVersionRaw : 0.0.0.0



https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Carbon/2.0.0/Content/Functions%5CGet-Msi.ps1

You can obtain the MSI Property "ProductVersion" with Get-AppLockerFileInformation. It only works if your MSI is digitally signed.
Get-AppLockerFileInformation -Path "C:\PathTo\my.msi" | Select -ExpandProperty Publisher | Select BinaryVersion

